# How can I detect if an Ansible playbook is executed by ansible-pull rather than ansible-playbook?

Tags: ansible

I am looking for a `when` condition which is fullfilled when the playbook is executed by ansible-pull.

Comment: I'm affraid you can't since `ansible-pull` actually runs `ansible-playbook` internally with no particular option once SCM checkout is done (run with `-vvv` to see the steps). If you use a specific directory on all your servers to clone your playbook repos from `ansible-pull`, you can eventually set a condition on the `playbook_dir` variable. This is way far from bulletproof though.

Answer (score 1):

I found two approaches to test if a playbook is applied via `ansible-pull`:

1. Check for `ansible_connection == "local"`. However this doesnt work in all places as local connections might also used regularily by your playbook.
2. Pass an extra variable to the invocation: `ansible-pull --extra-vars "ansible_pull=true"`